# Unexpected inner join behavior

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I've a query :

```
select  TABLE.NAME,
  max(case when TABLE_ADDITION.CODE= 1 then TABLE_ADDITION.VALUE end) Mach1,
  max(case when TABLE_ADDITION.CODE= 4 then TABLE_ADDITION.VALUE end) Source,
  max(case when TABLE_ADDITION.CODE= 6 then TABLE_ADDITION.VALUE end) Dest,
  max(case when TABLE_ADDITION.CODE= 16 then TABLE_ADDITION.VALUE end) Mach2
 FROM TABLE
```

This is working, the result is :

```
NAME     Mach1      Source       Dest      Mach2
test     11         testS        testD     12
```

I need another information from another table (MACH). Columns Mach1 and mach2 are IDs. I want to use this ID to take the name from the correct table MACH (see data below - end of the post).

I want to have :

```
NAME     Mach1          Source       Dest      Mach2
test     machName11     testS        testD     machName12
```

For that, I did :

```
   select  TABLE.NAME,
      max(case when TABLE_ADDITION.CODE= 1 then MACH.MACHNAME end) Mach1,
      max(case when TABLE_ADDITION.CODE= 4 then TABLE_ADDITION.VALUE end) Source,
      max(case when TABLE_ADDITION.CODE= 6 then TABLE_ADDITION.VALUE end) Dest,
      max(case when TABLE_ADDITION.CODE= 16 then MACH.MACHNAME end) Mach2
     FROM TABLE
     INNER JOIN TABLE_ADDITION ON TABLE.TABLEID = TABLE_ADDITION.TABLEID AND TABLE.NAME = TABLE_ADDITION.NAME
     INNER JOIN MACH ON TABLE_ADDITION.CODE IN (1, 16) AND TABLE_ADDITION .VALUE = MACH.MACHID
```

However, I didn't receive my expected behavior :

```
NAME     Mach1          Source       Dest      Mach2
test     machName11     NULL         NULL      machName12
```

I tried for LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN.

**Data for TABLE_ADDITION :**

```
TABLEID       NAME    CODE     VALUE
1             test    1        11
1             test    4        testS
1             test    6        testD
1             test    16       12
1             test    20       value11
1             test    25       45
1             test    ... [continue with a lot of ID and VALUE are int or varchar]
2             test2    1        45
2             test2    4        testSource\test
2             test2    6        testDest\test
2             test2    16       1
2             test2    20       value
2             test2    25       76
[continue for other ID]
```

**For MACH**

```
MACHID    MACHNAME    MACHTYPE
0         test        0
3         test1       1
10        test3       2
11        machName11  2
12        machName12  2
[continue with other ID]
```

**For TABLE**

```
TABLEID    NAME   TABLETYPE
1          test   12
1          test3  12
2          name   5
[continue with other ID]
```

I need the TABLE because it's my main table (with other column), I select some of them without issue.

EDIT, I edit my post, it was wrong and missing too much data to understand my issue.

For now it's working because I added one join :

```
   select  TABLE.NAME,
      max(case when t2.CODE= 1 then MACH.MACHNAME end) Mach1,
      max(case when TABLE_ADDITION.CODE= 4 then TABLE_ADDITION.VALUE end) Source,
      max(case when TABLE_ADDITION.CODE= 6 then TABLE_ADDITION.VALUE end) Dest,
      max(case when t2.CODE= 16 then MACH.MACHNAME end) Mach2
     FROM TABLE
     INNER JOIN TABLE_ADDITION ON TABLE.TABLEID = TABLE_ADDITION.TABLEID AND TABLE.NAME = TABLE_ADDITION.NAME
     INNER JOIN TABLE_ADDITION t2 ON TABLE.TABLEID = t2 .TABLEID AND TABLE.NAME = t2 .NAME
     INNER JOIN MACH ON t2 .CODE IN (1, 16) AND t2 .VALUE = MACH.MACHID
```

Thanks

Comment: What you need is a [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot)

Comment: I have the expected behavior for the line/column convertion. I'm not sure that pivot will change my left inner join.

Comment: I'm afraid that you asked an unclear question.  I don't understand why my answer doesn't work for you, and I also don't know the reason fro joining to `MACH` when you don't retain any columns from this table.

Comment: I think the Name comes from that, even though it's not selected in the example posted here. In the results it is included.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update the last query. I did it with the correct name.

Comment: I also think you need to at least clarify the question a little. If you are having to do with different types of the same column, consider casting properly and concatenating your list to use in the `IN` clause.

Comment: I updated the post. Is it clear?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem (I use left join), your query works exactly as you wants. Please write full query: declare @table_variable, populate it  and select in one query

Comment: I can post my test query in answer if you want an example

Comment: Also you shouldn't create a `MACHID` as `VARCHAR`. These columns usually have `INT` type.

Comment: I'll update my post.... I did a bad mistake ! I tried to clean more I can and I forgot a big part (the most important and my mistake was inside). I used one join to join the mach table and I did a mistake inside. I'll updated my code in consequence